# Return sum value of filtered/visible list

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks: "TEST" and "Report". I have used the following code:

```
MsgBox Sum_Visible_Cells(Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("M2:M" & LastRow(Worksheets("Raw Data"))))
```

and it returns the sum value in a messagebox. I have also been able to return the sum in a cell on the worksheet "Raw Data" in the workbook "TEST".

How can I make excel return the value in worksheet "Sheet1" , range "L9" on the workbook "Report"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need vba to do this.  In cell `Sheet1!L9` enter the formula

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,'Raw Data'!$M:$M)
```

To do it in VBA use

```
Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = "Result of your function"
```

Note: you must include file extension, and the workbook must be open.

EDIT:
`Sum_Visible_Cells` is not a worksheet function.

try this (assuming the code is in workbook `Test`)

```
Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns(13))
```

From your comment `Range("M2:M)` I guess you want to exclude row 1 from the total.
So long as `M1` is not numeric summing the whole column will be fine.  If row 1 *is* numeric and you want to exclude it try

```
Dim rng as Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2,13), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
End With 
Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rng)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. But I do need a VBA code for it. and I am aware of subtotal. There is UDF for summing visible cells on MSDN. But I am also able to use it. But I am not sure how I can get the result in a cell on another workbook.

Comment: Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = WorksheetFunction.Sum_Visible_Cells(Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("M2:M)) - will this work ? I had the logic figured out. The only problem is my lack of VBA knowledge. I tried to do the same, but I think the syntax was wrong.

Comment: Hi Chris - yes, I am getting ever so closer. The code is in the "Report" sheet. I think the second piece of code will do.

Comment: Set MyRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:AJ" & LastRow(Worksheets(1)))
        MyRange.Parent.Select
        With MyRange
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=""
            .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="Open"
            .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="May"
            .AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=""
            .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="*"
            End With
       Application.Workbooks("Canada Daily OEFC (Pune - Red Ibox) Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rng)

Comment: Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = _     Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rng) - this is fine. How do I return sum for the range "AB" ?

Comment: Dim rng as Range With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")     Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2,13), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp)) End With  Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9") = _     Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rng) - This code works -but when change it to "AB" (i.e. - 28) - it shows summed value as "0" , whereas the column has values.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done in the order you describe?

If you use the suggestion in the attached link ["VBA to get value from closed file"](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/) to add the GetValue function (make public) to retrieve the information from the Test Workbook you would have:

In TEST Workbook:

- Create a range containing your existing formula **e.g. Sheet1, Cell A1**
  Sum_Visible_Cells(Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("M2:M" &
  LastRow(Worksheets("Raw Data")))) formula

In REPORT Workbook use the GetValue() function in Sheet1 Cell L9 :

```
=GetValue(p, f, s, a)
```

where

- p = "Path to TEST Workbook"
- f = "TEST.xls"
- s = "Sheet1"
- a = "A1"

Comment: nice idea - but the value does not reside in any cell on any worksheet in " TEST" workbook. The UDF has to calculate the sum of values in the visible cells and return the sum to a cell in "Report" workbook, worksheet "Sheet1". Needless to say, I am making a management summary ( hence the word "report") and I have filter and get counts and sums from raw data file.

Comment: a bit confused. In your message you say you return the sum in a cell on the worksheet "Raw Data" in TEST workbook. Why not use that as a source in the Report workbook using above?

Comment: sum visible rows ( after applying filters) in worksheet "Raw Data", in workbook "TEST" - and then that value ( sum of values in column AB of worksheet "Raw Data") goes into cell "L9" of workbook "Report"